# JSF calling compositon in composition not working

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to call my composition from a composition, but nothing happens. Any idea why?

First call from template:

```
<div id="content">
    <ui:insert name="example" />
</div>
```

Now composition calls composition :

```
<ui:composition template="/template.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
    <ui:define name="example">
        <ui:include src="/PathToOtherComposition.xhtml"/>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-templating-with-facelets-example/

Comment: is your `template="/template.xhtml"` correct with the spelling and path? also does your `<ui:include src="/PathToOtherComposition.xhtml"/>` has a `template` attribute specified?

Comment: Yes both path and template attribute are specified